# How can i bake a texture for a large plane on which I've used a seamless texture

Tags: texturing, uv

Ive used a seamless texture to make a brick wall, it is a square texture, and I've just scaled up the UV map beyond the image constraints in order to repeat the texture over the large plane, I'm now trying to bake the lighting etc. onto a texture, but instead of baking the entire plane, it bakes a small area

I've tried making the image texture im baking onto, the same proportion as the plane but it bakes a smaller area that looks stretched

is it just a problem i have with the UV mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For baking you often want 2 UV maps: one for reading the source texture appropriately (exceeding bounds or just filling a small part) and one for baking (optimally filling the entire texture space). You can control which UV channel is active with baking via the little camera icon next to UV maps.

Comment: thank you, I initially thought that i should use the mapping node to repeat the texture instead of stretching the Uv map out of the bounds of the image, would that be a better workflow in general?